# Share TS types between Node.js(express) and React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

i have 2 separate projects(repositories)

```
/projects
 
-/Server/
--/Server/package.json
--/Server/tsconfig.json
--/Server/types/RestApiTypes.ts
 
-/React-Native/
--/React-Native/package.json
--/React-Native/tsconfig.json
--/React-Native/App.tsx
```

I want to use types from RestApiTypes.ts in App.tsx without building a monorepo(as i heard this is a PITA for RN).
As i understand i cannot use TS mapping because of different paths for different files in /React-native/ folder.
How can i simply do this having the autocomplete and autoimport and not turning /projects into a repository?

Comment: You could for instance create  a symolic link to the `/Server/types` directory in your `React-Native` project. But that would mean, your project will only be compileable if the `Server` is available at the exact correct location ...

Comment: derpirscher
thanks. definitely work for my local needs.